# SQL Compare Command-line does not synchronize database

Tags: batch-file, command-line, redgate, sqlcompare

In order to automate database synchronization using the SQL Compare command line; I have created a project to compare and deploy from my local database to a database in another server. Then I create a bat file. here is my bat file:

> SET curdir=%~dp0
>
> SET sqlcompare="C:\Program Files (x86)\Red Gate\SQL Compare 13\sqlcompare.exe"
>
> %sqlcompare% /project:"%curdir%IcLoyalty.scp" /sync /include:Identical

The result of command is:

> Registering data sources
>
> Creating mappings
>
> Comparing
>
> Summarizing Project Selections
>
> Retrieving migration scripts
>
> Checking for identical databases
>
> Creating SQL
>
> Deploying changes (from DB1 to DB2)

When I check the destination database the changes does not apply. Consider that project work correctly when I open it with SQL Compare Application.
What I've missed in bat file?

Comment: Looks like it should work. Can you add /scriptFile:deployscript.sql and inspect the file to see if the changes are reflected there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that you had your selection (the checkboxes on the comparison results) deselected when you saved the project. Try selecting them all and resave the project.

This is from the [documentation page](https://documentation.red-gate.com/sc11/using-the-command-line/switches-used-in-the-command-line#Switchesusedinthecommandline-/IncludeIdentical:%3CIncludeIdentical%3E).
"If you want to include or exclude objects from an existing project, you must modify your selection using the graphical user interface."